# How can I edit the action of the buttons in the dialog box in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dialog

This code is from the demo of modal confirmation from jQuery's site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        overlay: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            opacity: 0.5
        },
        buttons: {
            'Yes': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'No': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>



<div class="demo">

<div id="dialog" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>

<!-- Sample page content to illustrate the layering of the dialog -->
<div class="hiddenInViewSource" style="padding:20px;">
    <p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
    <form>
        <input value="text input" /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" />checkbox<br />
        <input type="radio" />radio<br />
        <select>
            <option>select</option>
        </select><br /><br />
        <textarea>textarea</textarea><br />
    </form>
</div><!-- End sample page content -->

</div><!-- End demo -->

<div class="demo-description">

<p>Confirm an action that may be destructive or important.  Set the <code>modal</code> option to true, and specify primary and secondary user actions with the <code>buttons</code> option.</p>

</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

Can anyone tell me how to edit the action for the buttons? When "Yes" is clicked I want to be redirected to `test.php`, and when I hit "No" I want to be redirected to another page.

Answer (score 1):

How to hook into the two buttons should be obvious, so I'm assuming your actual question is "how do you redirect with javascript". Here's how:

```
window.location = "http://something.com/foo"
```

If you aren't sure where to put this snippet, read your code out loud and you'll figure it out.

Comment: Since you're new here: If my post answered your question, click the "answered" checkmark on it, so that it's tagged as accepted.

Comment: another question how can i integrate this with a button? i mean when i run this code the dialog box automatically appears. how can i make it appear only after hitting a button?

Comment: @noob, check out the documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog  Supply autoOpen: false in the dialog's object.  Then, in a click event for a button or link, you'd do: `$("#dialog").dialog('show');`